# Rearranging Array Alternately[Memory Error]

Tags: python

I try to solve a questions from geeksforgeeks.org on question about "Rearrange Array Alternately", when trying on the sample input, I did not receive any errors but when I try to submit it then i receive "memory Error"

```
test_cases = "1"
for _ in range(int(test_cases)):
    new_array = []
    array_size = int("89")
    array = list(map(int, "1 9 16 18 72 88 98 100 127 128 150 155 160 174 185 196 198 200 218 226 267 270 279 284 299 309 326 335 335 351 355 369 383 394 399 400 413 422 422 429 438 440 446 483 507 529 529 542 553 556 567 571 578 594 611 640 642 652 658 658 663 673 694 717 723 736 762 763 775 777 778 784 806 816 828 851 853 854 889 891 911 932 953 955 958 973 977 986 998 ".split()))
    while len(array) != 0:
        if len(array) == 1:
            new_array.append(array[0])
            array.remove(array[0])
        else:
            max_array_value = max(array)
            min_array_value = min(array)
            new_array.append(max_array_value)
            new_array.append(min_array_value)
            array.remove(max_array_value)
            array.remove(min_array_value)
```

*Side notes: Lets just ignore why I use it in string format and not integer due to me trying to replicate the input from geeksforgeeks.org. *

The current codes work only on the small array but not a very large array. When I try to create a list of more than 100 integers then it will give me the error. I am wondering whether is there any work around for solving such a problem?

Comment: Why do you use `array_size = int("11")` instead of just `array_size=11`?  There are several places where you use this kind of construction.

Comment: I don't have problems starting with `array = list(range(1000))`.  You'll have to give a more concrete, reproducible example that gives the error.

Comment: The reason why I used string format because I wanted to replicate the input I get from geeksforgeeks.org. It doesnt matter it is in integer or string format because what I concern the most is the memory error not the formatting

Comment: Yes hpaulj, in the case of using our own laptop, it works good but when I try to submit this answer to geeksforgeeks.org, we received memory error, probably due to the low memory provided by the system to test our skills in making sure that not wasting too much of memory in codings.

Comment: Have you seen the tracebaxk from the memory error?

Comment: yes, line 5, in <module>
    array = list(map(int, input().split()))

Comment: Building a number list from a string like that will take up more memory, at least temporarily than the equivalent `alist [1, 9, 16, 18, 72, 88, 98 ...]`.  There's the space for the string, the list of substrings (from `split`), and then the conversion of each to integer.  Still I think the real culprit is the low allocated memory on the remote machine.

Comment: Yes, its like hpaulj you said, the allocated memory in the remote machine is very low and a lot of people are trying change their algorithms when doing the tutorials. since I am not as good as you all in python and coding so I need to get more experience and it seems like they purposely allocate it that low so that beginners like us can take note of not over using the memory, that is what I guess. Thanks and I will test on it.

Comment: Do you think is it possible to solve this issue for line 5? Instead of making it a list?

Comment: The error occurs right at the start, when setting up the problem.  If working with the larger list isn't essential to the problem, I wouldn't worry about it.  You know if it works for a normal machine.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will just skip submitting this exercise on the web. Will proceed with others. Thank you again and sorry that I could not vote for any of comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
def rearrange(arr, n): 

    k,j=1,1
    a=[0]*n
    for i in range(0,n):

        if i%2==0:
            a[i]=arr[n-k]
            k=k+1

        else:
            a[i]=arr[i-j]
            j=j+1
    for i in range(n):
        arr[i]=a[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution mentioned below solves the problem in **O(N) Time complexity** and **O(1) Space Complexity** **WITHOUT** using the *"storing 2 values at one location concept"*. Moreover this algorithm can also handle duplicate values & float values given the input list is non-decreasingly sorted and consists of positive real numbers only.

PS: If you wish you can modify my algorithm slightly to make it work for negative values as well.

**Please don't get intimidated by looking at the code. Implementation is very simple.

Algorithm might be a bit tricky to understand.**

```py
    def reArrange(arr, print_arr_state=True):
        # arr: non-decreasingly sorted list of positive floats/ints
        length = len(arr)
        for i in range(length):
            if arr[i] > 0:
                cycler(arr, i, length, print_arr_state)
            arr[i] = abs(arr[i]) # This is the tricky part
            # printing the array after every iteration
            if print_arr_state:
                print('after', i, 'th iteration:', arr)


    def cycler(arr, start_index, length, print_cycler_array=True):
        if print_cycler_array:
            print('cycler function:', arr, end=' ---> ')

        half_length_index = length // 2
        swap_index = start_index
        current_value = arr[start_index]
        while True:
            if swap_index < half_length_index:
                swap_index = 2 * swap_index + 1
            else:
                swap_index = 2 * (length - 1 - swap_index)

            # Placing the current value at swap_index and making the making current_value variable refer to the value which was at swap_index
            swap_value = arr[swap_index]
            arr[swap_index] = -1 * current_value # -1 * ?? This is the tricky part of the algo
            current_value = swap_value

            # cycler function will not stop until the simple cycle is complete
            # simple cycle is complete when swap_index == start_index
            if swap_index == start_index:
                if print_cycler_array:
                    print(arr)
                return
```

**Giving Input (input_array) and Calling reArrange function:**

```
input_array = [0.1, 2, 3.2, 3.3, 3.3, 4, 5.7, 5.7, 6.8, 7, 8, 9]
reArrange(input_array)
```

**Output:**

```
answer_array = [9, 0.1, 8, 2, 7, 3.2, 6.8, 3.3, 5.7, 3.3, 5.7, 4]
```

### Understanding the algorithm

#### Tricky part of the algorithm:

Every value belongs to exactly 1 cycle and this cycle is a simple cycle (simple cycle vs complex cycle in graphs). One execution of *cycler* function corresponds to one cycle which is also a simple cycle.

Whenever I cover a value during a cycle, I multiply it with -1 (to indicate that it is covered) and store it in the input array itself.
During the i-th iteration of the loop of *reArrange* function, if I find the i-th value to be negative I get an indication that this value is a part of a cycle executed for some j-th iteration (where j < i), thus I don't call the *cycler* function on this value. But if this value is positive (indicating that none of cycles executed so far has covered this value), it implies that it is not covered yet and hence should be covered in the i-th iteration using the *cycler* function.

But wait!, if I have multiplied all values with -1 my final answer will be **-1 * *correct_answer_array***. To solve this problem, one solution is to reiterate my *answer_array* (which was *input_array* initially and now has transformed to my *answer_array*) and take the absolute of each value **OR** I can do the same thing during my first and only iteration (of *reArrange* function's loop) by taking the absolute of the value before moving to the i+1-th iteration.

### Some valid questions

There are few aspects of this algorithm that I haven't covered in this post. Let me leave you with some of these aspects in the form of questions:

1. Is the while loop of *cycler* function guaranteed to terminate?
2. Why should we not cover a value more than once?
3. How can we handle the negative input values (if any)?
4. Isn't a single cycle sufficient to cover all the values of the input_array. (Isn't a single call of the *cycler* function sufficient to cover all the values)?
   Hint: eg: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7, this example will lead to 3 cycles. (*cycler* function will be called thrice)
5. What happens during a single call of cycler function?
   Hint: Every value which is the part of this cycle shifts to the place where it is supposed to be in the *correct_answer_array*. Once a value is at its correct place, it should not be disturbed again.

> This algorithm is completely a new and original approach so more the
> number of people verify it the better it is for its acceptance as a
> better alternative than *"storing two values at one location concept"*.

Please visit the comments section at the bottom of [this page (GeeksforGeeks)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rearrange-array-maximum-minimum-form) to see the dry run of the algorithm. Please make sure you read all of the comments by me because it is broken in parts there.